# Typescript Loop with Delay

Tags: javascript, loops, typescript, delay

I'm trying to create a metronome with Typescript.

I have this javascript code:

```
(function theLoop (i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            metronome.play();
            if (--i) {
                theLoop(i);
            }
        }, 3000);          // interval set to 3000
    })(10);                // play it 10 times
```

And I wanted to convert it into Typescript code. Unfortunately I don't know how to do this (espacially regarding the last line => `})(10);`

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: TypeScript is just a superset of JavaScript. On the other hand, the metronome should probably have a way of changing it's tempo and a way of starting it and stopping it as well as making it tick on demand. Basically I'd expect `metronome.changeTempo(bpm); metronome.onTick(function () { if (...) metronome.stop(); }); metronome.play();`. You could also have a built-in feature specific to ticking a number of times. `metronome.tick(10)`.

Comment: @plalx I like your idea! What would the code look like? Or: How can I approach it?

Comment: Do you know a bit of OO? Look at the `class` keyword and examples on how to use it. Metronome would be a class here, not an Audio file. It could take an audio as a constructor parameter though.. `let metronome = new Metronome(new Audio('tick.mp3'))`.

Comment: @plalx Do you know a tutorial regarding this topic? Because I'm unfortunately not this far in OO...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As everyone said, typescipt is a superset of javascript so your code is valid typescript, but here's how to do it with an arrow function (which is also `es6` javascript) and types:

```
(function theLoop (i: number) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            metronome.play();
            if (--i) {
                theLoop(i);
            }
        }, 3000);
    })(10);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=(function%20theLoop%20(i%3A%20number)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20metronome.play()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(--i)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20theLoop(i)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%203000)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)(10)%3B))

And here's another variation:

```
let theLoop: (i: number) => void = (i: number) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        metronome.play();
        if (--i) {
            theLoop(i);
        }
    }, 3000);
};

theLoop(10);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20theLoop%3A%20(i%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20void%20%3D%20(i%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20metronome.play()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(--i)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20theLoop(i)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%203000)%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0AtheLoop(10)%3B))

---

#### Edit

Using the 2nd option I gave you, changing the delay is easy:

```
let theLoop: (i: number, delay?) => void = (i: number, delay = 3000) => {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
        delay = 1500;
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
        metronome.play();
        if (--i) {
            theLoop(i);
        }
    }, delay);
};

theLoop(10);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20theLoop%3A%20(i%3A%20number%2C%20delay%3F)%20%3D%3E%20void%20%3D%20(i%3A%20number%2C%20delay%20%3D%203000)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(i%20%25%202%20%3D%3D%3D%200)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20delay%20%3D%201500%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20metronome.play()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(--i)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20theLoop(i)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20delay)%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0AtheLoop(10)%3B))

Comment: Thanks! But is there any way to change the interval (3000) after I started theLoop? Because now, when I change the number, theLoop still continues until it played the sound 10 times...

Comment: Wow, this looks amazing. Unfortunately I still get a second overlapping metronome, if I change the delay/interval. Also, the performance is now really bad (the delays aren't strictly in time)...

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do so I can't help you with that. You wanted to know how to convert your js code to ts, and that's what I answered. If you have some specific in mind then better ask it, probably as a new question if it's not related to your original one.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I opened a new question and gave more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40920820/typescript-metronome

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`Typescript` is a upperset of `Javascript`. So you can copy your code into `Typescript` and it will work