# Typescript Metronome

Tags: javascript, loops, angular, typescript, delay

I'm trying to build a metronome with Typescript (and Angular 2).
Thanks, to @Nitzan-Tomer ([Typescript Loop with Delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40919088/typescript-loop-with-delay/40919666)), who helped me with the basics.

Now I'm facing the issue, that after I started the metronome, I'm not able to change the interval. Imagine a slider, changing the speed between the sounds (=> interval).

```
let theLoop: (i: number) => void = (i: number) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        metronome.play();
        if (--i) {
            theLoop(i);
        }
    }, 3000);
};

theLoop(10);
```

The interval here is 3000. And I want to be able to change it, after the function was triggered. (Maybe also get rid of the `i: number`? Because it shouldn't just play the metronome-sound 10 times...

I thought of a class? But I'm not sure how to build it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the interval of SetInterval while it's running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280263/changing-the-interval-of-setinterval-while-its-running)

Comment: Not specifically about the question but I suggest you use more descriptive function names. `theLoop` doesn't tell the reader what your function does. Something like `startMetronomeCycle()` might be better.

Comment: Unfortunately they're using SetInterval and the DOM... I try to build a plain javascript/typescript/angular2 metronome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple class to do it:

```
class Metronome {
    private interval: number;
    private timer: number;

    constructor(interval = 3000) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    start(): void {
        this.tick();
    }

    stop() {
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }

    setInterval(interval: number) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    private tick() {
        // do something here
        this.timer = setTimeout(this.tick.bind(this), this.interval);
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Metronome%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20interval%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20timer%3A%20number%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(interval%20%3D%203000)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.interval%20%3D%20interval%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20start()%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.tick()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20stop()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20clearTimeout(this.timer)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20setInterval(interval%3A%20number)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.interval%20%3D%20interval%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20private%20tick()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20do%20something%20here%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.timer%20%3D%20setTimeout(this.tick.bind(this)%2C%20this.interval)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D))

Comment: Why don't you implement the `setInterval(interval: number)` directly into `start(interval: number)`?

Comment: I think it's wise to separate the two. The `tick` method is being called repeatedly, and the `start` method is the symmetric counterpart of `stop`. Also, you might want to do more things in `start` which you won't want to repeat.